.NET Core 8 site on IIS 10 rejecting PATCH, PUT, DELETE requests
I've been adding an API to a .NET Core 8 website. When I run it locally in IIS Express out of Visual Studio, all the PATCH, PUT, and DELETE requests work. When I deploy to IIS 10 on a server, they're rejected, returning 404 (not 405). The requests do get as far as being recorded in IIS's logs, which show that the error is, more specifically, 404.6 (Not Found - The requesting filtering module is configured to deny the HTTP verb).
GET and POST requests succeed as they have all along.
I've made all the adjustments I can find through online research to web.config, but to no avail--removing WebDAV, removing and readding aspNetCore and ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 handlers with the full verb list spelled out. One addition I tried was the following in the <security> section, but I removed it because the site wouldn't relaunch as long as any of the add tags were in it.
<requestFiltering>
  <verbs>
    <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
    <add verb="HEAD" allowed="true" />
    <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
    <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
    <add verb="PATCH" allowed="true" />
    <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
    <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="true" />
  </verbs>
</requestFiltering>

I tried adding corresponding <remove> tags before the <add>s in redundant adds were the problem, but that didn't help. The <requestFiltering> and <verbs> tags caused no problem as long as the <verbs> section was empty.
So this is what I'm left with. Can anyone figure out something else to try?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.web>
            <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />  
        </system.web>
        <system.webServer>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
                <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
            </modules>
            <httpProtocol>
                <customHeaders>
                    <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
                    <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-hashes' 'sha256-[...]/[...]';" />
                    <add name="Referrer-Policy" value="same-origin" />
                </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
            <rewrite>
                <outboundRules>
                    <rule name="Use only secure cookies" preCondition="Unsecured cookie">
                        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_SET_COOKIE" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
                        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; secure" />
                    </rule>
                    <preConditions>
                        <preCondition name="Unsecured cookie">
                            <add input="{RESPONSE_SET_COOKIE}" pattern="." />
                            <add input="{RESPONSE_SET_COOKIE}" pattern="; secure" negate="true" />
                        </preCondition>
                    </preConditions>
                </outboundRules>
            </rewrite>
            <handlers>
                <remove name="WebDAV" />
                <remove name="WebAdminHandler-Integrated" />
                <remove name="aspNetCore" />
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
                <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
                <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"
                    path="*."
                    verb="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS"
                    type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
                    preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Frb.Mispl.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
                <environmentVariables>
                    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
                </environmentVariables>
            </aspNetCore>
            <security>
                <authentication>
                    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                    <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
                </authentication>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>


I decided to look in my own computer's applicationHost.config, used by IIS Express which is what Visual Studio runs, to see if there were any clues, and I found, in the <security> section,
<requestFiltering>
  <verbs allowUnlisted="true" applyToWebDAV="false" />
</requestFiltering>

I added that to web.config on the server and my requests started to work. They continued to work after I rolled back all the other changes I'd tried.
